How do I configure Terraria to treat a jump key press as a tap rather than a hold?
In Terraria, I am trying to always do the minimum jump. I would like to make it so pressing the jump key is treated as tapping it instantly and not held at all. 
I have a Windows 10 laptop. How would I go about doing this?

Not specifically related to terraria but okay

"Not specifically related to terraria but okay" If your question isn't specifically about a video game, then it's likely to be closed here. Keep in mind that this site is dedicated to video game-related queries only. General software or computer questions don't quite fit the scope here. If that's what you're asking about, you might want to check out the Super User site at https://superuser.com/. They're better equipped to handle those kinds of questions.

Your best option would be to adjust your keyboard properties (Settings, search for Keyboard settings) repeat rate and repeat delay. If you change it to a long delay and a slow repeat rate it would require a much longer press to have it register as a "held" key and can accomplish a "tap" feature.

However if you're looking for a way to simulate repeated taps, you'll need an external application like AutoHotKey to record/play key sequences. Some gaming keyboards will come with software that allows you to do this.

Edit: After edit to the question, you would have to play around with the settings to achieve that. I would start with a shorter repeat delay, but a long repeat rate to simulate a quick tap. This would also help if you wanted to prevent multiple small taps (adjust the delay if you want quicker/longer presses between taps).

wouldnt editing "keyboard properties" like that affect all keys?

Yes it would. But as mentioned there is software that can do it too.
